# How to define Composite primary key, which doesn't allow even the reverse combination

Tags: mysql, database-design, constraints, primary-key, ddl

I am building a friend list for an App, and i was wondering if its possible to define the keys / indexes on a table in a way that it wouldn't allow the inverse combination of the keys.

For example, let's say that the table has columns like these:

```
user_id1, user_id2, status, [..timestamps]
```

The primary key is the composite key made of `user_id1` and `user_id2`. Nothing special so far. You might would store data similar to this:

```
+----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| user_id1 |  user_id2 | status   | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|        3 |         1 |    1     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|        2 |         3 |    1     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

But this way there is no constraint which would deny you to insert `1, 3` or `3, 2` for `user_id1` and `user_id2` respectively - like so:

```
+----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| user_id1 |  user_id2 | status   | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|        3 |         1 |    1     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|        2 |         3 |    1     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|        1 |         3 |    1     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|        3 |         2 |    1     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

In this case it doesn't matter who is user1 or user2, all it matters is are the linked or not. Duplicates wouldn't necessarily ruin the code, but it would be nice to enforce the rules in MySQL too.

Comment: Please use clear language to express your requirement. It can barely be made out.

Comment: I'm waving a red flag of danger over here.  Can you see me?  Any time you have two or more columns in the same table whose values come from the same information domain, you're (arguably) violating the relational model, and (less arguably) setting yourself up for queries you're going to hate, sooner or later.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I had a feeling. Can you recommend an alternative structure?

Comment: Some things are best done in the application, not SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't really care which user is `user_id1` and which is `user_id2`, I'd just make an arbitrary decision that `user_id1` is the lower id (and make sure the application sorts the two when inserting, of course!).

This way, you can enforce uniqueness with two constraints - first, a composite primary key like you suggested:

```
ALTER TABLE friendship
ADD CONSTRAINT friendship_pk
PRIMARY KEY (user_id1, user_id2)
```

Second, you'll need a check constraint to ensure that `user_id1` is indeed the smaller id, as discussed above:

```
ALTER TABLE friendship
ADD CONSTRAINT friendship_ids_check
CHECK (user_id1 < user_id2)
```

Comment: That is an interesting and out-of-the-box approach; will try Sir!

Comment: @zedling & Mureinik MySQL Still does not enforce CHECK constraints (although it parses them).

Comment: that seems to be the case, i can save even the same values to the two fields, and it doesn't raises an error. My only idea is some kind of trigger before insert/update

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL just skips the CHECK constrain. [See this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html)
`The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.`